# How to check if derived class was fully constructed

Tags: c++, c++14

What I am looking for is a way for a `Base` class detect that the `Derived` class was not fully constructed.  There is some logic in the `Base` destructor that I only want executed if the `Derived` class was fully constructed.  I don't want to modify the implementations of `Derived` at all. I could modify `Derived` with a flag that gets set at the end of the destructor, but I was hoping for some trick that does this automatically.

```
class Base {
public:
   ~Base() { 
      if (FullyConstructed()) {cout << "fatal program bug"; abort();}
   }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
   Derived()
   {
      if (Something()) throw std::runtime_error("oh oh");
   }
   ~Derived() { }
};

main()
{
     Derived d;
}
```

When this runs, `Base` gets constructed, `Derived` does not get constructed fully because it throws, then immediate `~Base` gets called.  Because `~Derived` is not called, `~Base` will call abort.

How do I implement `FullyConstructed()` in the `Base` class? Is there a way to detect that the vtable for `Derived` wasn't constructed?

Comment: Did you mean `class Derived : public Base`?

Comment: `~Base() : foo(false)` ... what is this?

Comment: The vtable and typeid of the object will be the base vtable and typeid when the base destructor is called, even if it’s not the most derived type, thus I believe it’s impossible to detect the derived class without it modifying the base while it is constructed.

Comment: Cannot be done without cooperation from derived class, during `Base::ctor,dtor` any derived classes no longer exist.

Comment: What _vtable_? It seems we're missing some info.

Comment: @FredLarson and TedLyngmo, thanks for pointing out my typos.  There is a vtable in my actual classes (as Base is abstract), I should have put some pure virtual function in the example.

Comment: @Quimby should I just give up?

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Comment: "*Because `~Derived` is not called, `~Base` will call abort*" - it will call `abort()` anyway because you are missing `{}` braces on the `if` block. `if (FullyConstructed()) cout << "fatal program bug"; abort();` is the same as `if (FullyConstructed()) { cout << "fatal program bug"; } abort();` so `abort()` will be called *unconditionally*. You want `if (FullyConstructed()) { cout << "fatal program bug"; abort(); }` instead, but the only way to implement `FullyConstructed()` is to add a `bool` data member to `Base` and have `Derived` update that `bool` if constructed successfully

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  What is not shown here: The `Base` class starts a thread. The `Derived` class has to join the thread, because the thread needs to shut down before the class is destroyed.  The `Base` class can't join the thread.  The `~Base` dtor verifies that the derived class joined the thread. If not, the program needs to come to a screeching halt and report a programmatic bug.  BUT, if the derived class throws an exception, it never joins the thread.  I want to catch the exception before abort is called. I realize that it is kludgy.  I am trying to learn more C++ tricks.

Comment: @MarkLakata That is a bad design. Why can't you simply start the thread after all of the constructors have exited first and you have a fully constructed object?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the typo correction. If I was designing the class structure from scratch, I would start the threads after construction.  But I don't want to refactor everything now.

Comment: @MarkLakata If `Base` is the one starting the thread, then `Base` should be the one to terminate the thread. If the thread has a dependency on `Derived` instead of `Base`, then the thread is not designed well. It is really hard to help you without seeing a real example of the actual limitation you are dealing with. You are not going to be able to solve this without some amount of refactoring

Comment: @MarkLakata if all you need to do is check if the thread was dealt with, you could use [std::thread::joinable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable) perhaps? (But I agree that this doesn't sound like a great long-term design.)

Comment: What if the `Derived` constructor throws after joining the thread? Merely checking if the `Derived` constructor finished normally might not be enough.

Comment: @MarkLakata _"if the derived class throws an exception, it never joins the thread"_ How come? Are you starting threads in constructors? Start them _after_ everything that can throw. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Well you could build your own way such as:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    bool DerivedIsFullyConstructed;

public:
    Base() : DerivedIsFullyConstructed(false)
    {
    }
    ~Base()
    { 
        if (DerivedIsFullyConstructed)
        {
            // whatever you want
        }
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
        // ... stuff
        
        DerivedIsFullyConstructed = true;
    }
};
```

But if I were to see such a thing in practice it would make me want to review the design to see if there's a better way.

Comment: Your `DerivedIsFullyConstructed` member is `private` to `Base` and not accessible to `Derived`.  You need take it `protected` instead.

Comment: The original request was to avoid modifying Derived.

Comment: @MarkLakata: Then I think you're out of luck.